# List of function applications in OCaml & OCaml model of evaluation

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm not too familiar with OCaml's model of evaluation. I'd be grateful if someone could explain why these two lines of code give different results:

```
List.iter (fun s -> Printf.printf "%s" s) ["a"; "b"; "c"];; (* prints abc *)

List.iter (fun f -> f) [Printf.printf "a"; Printf.printf "b"; Printf.printf "c"];; (* prints cba *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml is a strict functional programming language: a function's arguments are evaluated as values (and side-effects in the expressions happen) before they are passed to the function (and any side-effects inside the function can happen).

In order to understand your second example, it is best to desugar it a bit:

`List.cons
  (Printf.printf "a")
  (List.cons (Printf.printf "b") (List.cons (Printf.printf "c") []))`

When a function is passed several arguments at once—as is the case for all `List.cons` functions here—the order of evaluation of the arguments is unspecified. This order can differ between the bytecode and the native compiler, for instance. Here, the compiler you used decided to evaluate the first `List.cons`'s second argument first. In doing this, it encountered an application (the second `List.cons`)

…

In evaluating the arguments of the last `List.cons`, it printed `c`. The result was `()`, which allowed it to build the value `[()]`. This argument being ready, it now evaluated the other argument of the second `List.cons`. That made it print `b`. Finally, since the argument `[();()]` of the first `List.cons` was ready, it evaluated the other argument. That made it print `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This certainly clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

As Pascal Cuoq already answered your question, let me just clear up a potential misunderstanding that I take from the question title: Nowhere in your code is a list of functions.

In the first line there is a list of strings, `["a";"b";"c"]`.

In the second line you have a list with elements such as `Printf.printf "a"`, which are function *applications*. Their resulting type is `unit`, also not a function type. (In fact the list is just `[();();()]`.)

An example of a list of funtions would be

```
[(fun () -> print_string "a"); (fun () -> print_string "b"); (fun () -> ())]
```

Comment: May I inquire what you mean by " the type of Printf.printf is not fully documented" ?  http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html and http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#TYPEformat detail both the type of printf and the meaning of the type parameters of the format type constructor.

Comment: @octachron: My mistake. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes indeed, that was just me being sloppy with the title.